# How to get current location on maps Xcode iOS 8?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, ios8

I am trying to implement Xcode maps on iOS 8 , and i followed geekylemon tutorial 
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Fr940DT1Z7Y

I think he is doing it on older SDK . Is there any video tutorials or github code that do this on iOS 8 with storyboards and map view?

And the classes  that I wrote with the tutorial are : 
**ViewController.h**

```
#import <MapKit/MapKit.h>
@interface ViewController :UIViewController {
MKMapView *mapview;
}
@property (nonatomic, retain) IBOutlet MKMapView *mapview;
@end
```

**ViewController.m**

```
@implementation ViewController
@synthesize mapview;
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
[super viewDidLoad];
// Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
   MKCoordinateRegion region = { {0.0, 0.0}, {0.0,0.0}};
   region.center.latitude = 40.707184;
   region.center.longitude = -73.998392;
   region.span.longitudeDelta = 0.01f;
   region.span.latitudeDelta = 0.01f;
   [mapview setRegion:region animated:YES];
 }

-(IBAction)GetLocation:(id)sender {
mapview.showsUserLocation = YES;
}

@end
```